# Filtering random Signal

Tags: matlab, filters, statistics, random

My question is easy one actually.

First, I generate a random signal using `randn()` function of MATLAB like this:

[image]

Then, I design a FIR filter of order 200 of pass-band characteristics with the pass-band $[0.2\pi, 0.4\pi]$ using the MATLAB function [`fir2()`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/signal/ref/fir2.html):

[image]

My questions are:

- What am I supposed to see when I filter a random signal using BPF?
- What change in the characteristics will be occur considering the theory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The output signal will still be normally distributed, but its power spectrum, i.e. its frequency content, will obviously be different from the input signal. If $S_X(\omega)$ is the power spectrum of the input signal, which is approximately flat, then the power spectrum of the output signal is

$$S_Y(\omega)=|H(\omega)|^2S_X(\omega)$$

where $H(\omega)$ is the frequency response of the filter.

Comment: Thanks for asnwer (:  Actually I am wondering what am I supposed to see in band pass filtered random signal in time domain? I have some trouble about filtering the random signal I mean I may be applying the filter wrongly so I want to deduce or verify it. How to consider this problem?

Comment: @mehmet: You should cross-check your filtering routine with some standard routine as provided by Matlab/Octave (`filter.m`) or some other package. You can't just look at the filtered time-domain signal and say, well that looks good, probably my filter works as it should.

Comment: Well I had planned to filter() function of MATLAB but it takes num and den of the filter as arguements. I have the values of the band pass filter in bot time and frequency domain. I don't know how I can get the num and den from this point?

Comment: @mehmet If `h` is the vector of filter coefficients returned from the function `fir2()`, and `x` is your random input signal, then you must use: `y=filter(h,1,x);`

Comment: Thank you very much @Matt L. I had supposed fir2 returns the values of the filter in time domain bu it is filter coefficients! Thanks again (:

Comment: @mehmet: That's the same thing for an FIR filter, the filter coefficients are the same as the impulse response.

Comment: The output will not be normally distributed, this is an error. The conditional  distribution is at best, a conditional multivariate gaussian distribution. Truncating the spectrum bends the distribution and the iid property is lost.

Comment: @hypfco: A Gaussian process filter by an LTI system remains Gaussian.

Comment: @MattL. The conditional 1 step ahead predictor distribution are gaussian, but the process (with IID samples) will not be gaussian. The integral operator output is a wiener process (not gaussian), and the output of a standard filter is between the wiener process and the iid gaussian process.

Answer (score 2):

You will be creating a random band-pass signal.

What you are *supposed to see* for such a signal if you plot the time sequence, is a varying sinusoid of frequency $0.3 \pi$ (midpoint of the pass band). Amplitude and phase will vary randomly, depending on the signal bandwidth.

In your case, $0.2 \pi$ bandwidth is quite large compared to the *carrier frequency* of $0.3 \pi$, so the result should look quite erratic.

For a smaller bandwidth, amplitude and phase will vary more smoothly.

Comment: This is very interesting! But I couldn't realize how I can deduce it would be a sinusoidal signal?

Comment: @mehmet: I'm afraid you won't see anything that is similar to a sinusoid. The one but last sentence of Juancho's answer ("...quite erratic ...") is more accurate than the description of the output signal as a "varying sinusoid of frequency $0.3\pi$". The latter would only be visible if the bandwidth was *much* smaller.

Comment: I see it is some kind of aliasing effect. If I used much smaller band width I would have almost a dirac in frequency domain and it would be a sinusoidal signal. Now I understand the idea. Thank to both of you guys! @MattL.